# How to use Kubernetes Client-Java API to get pod logs

Tags: java, logging, kubernetes

Is there an API call in the [Kubernetes-Client/Java library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) to get a log for specific pod. Something equivalent to `kubectl logs <POD>`.

Comment: This is a question regarding java library. The one you linked is for go library.

Comment: you are probably looking for the method [readNamespacedPodLog](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#readNamespacedPodLog)